# How do I detect the "conversation" pattern in SQL?

Tags: algorithm

Actually, this is not specific to SQL, and I doubt "conversation pattern" is the correct name, but I could not think of a better caption.

To simplify, imagine you got a vast stream of ints. The task is to detect an `A.{1;max_n}A` pattern: An int satisfies the pattern if it is followed by n (> 0) other ints, then the original int again, while n <= max_n.

Example:

```
...
1
4 <--
7 \
3  > n = 3
3 /
4 <--
2
...
```

Here, the int `4` is repeated with 3 arbitrary ints in-between, so for max_n <= 3 the pattern is satisfied for the value `4`.

The question is, how can I detect which integers in the huge dump of data follow this pattern? I'm mostly interested in the algorithm itself, but an example in SQL or C# would be welcome, too.

The naive idea I came up with is to first gather a list or all distinct ints, then check the pattern in a straightforward way for each of them, but that would lead to a performance bottleneck.

Comment: perhaps use a numbers table?...

Comment: sorry, what is a numbers table?

Comment: SQL operates on sets: it's really not designed for comparing rows in the output set, so it's a poor choice for this sort of analysis.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, it is a poor choice, but not because of your argument, but because it optimizes generically and is biased towards secondary memory data access paths. There is nothing that says that you can not select a subset of a set, based on certain properties. The keyword that suggests SQL is wrong tool for a job is *stream* of numbers, which suggest in memory structures and need/possibility for more efficient algorithm then your stock SQL query planner (and predetermined indexing methods).

Comment: I didn't suggest you couldn't select subsets based on the properties of the elements. My point is that he's trying to do an operation that depends on relationships between rows in a result set, which is not what SQL is built for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold some dictionary (C#) or map (C++) structure where will be saved position of first occurrence of numbers.

Then for every number you should check if it present in map. If yes - you should compare position difference with maximum position difference occurred before. Otherwise you should save the number and its position in map.

Comment: Your idea might be the simplest way and still quite effective. Sounds about O(n * log n) to me.

Comment: If used data structure will be implemented via hashes then you can achieve O(n) complexity

Comment: Indeed, my mistake, with a reasonable hash function it would be `O(n)`, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQL will not do it in an optimal way, but it might not be horrible if the columns are indexed.

First, to speak of order in SQL you should have another column. If that column is actually equal to a row number then you can:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.number
FROM 
  table t1, table t2
WHERE
  (t1.rownumber-t2.rownumber) <= @max_n AND
  (t1.rownumber-t2.rownumber) >=1 AND
  t1.number = t2.number AND
```